# Разделение приложения на backend и frontend части

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет, встал вопрос разделение приложение на логические части, ну т.е. как минимум backend, frontend. Как я себе представляю структуру приложения:

```
-app
    -backend
        -controllers
        -models
        -helpers
        -assets
        -views
    -frontend
        -controllers
        -models
        -helpers
        -assets
        -views
    -common
        -controllers
        -models
        -helpers
        -assets
        -views
```

На данный момент я не знаю, возможно ли это реализовать в рельсах, гугление пока не помогло, но считаю что такая структура будет гораздо лучше чем создавать в одном application-е разделение типа

```
-controllers
    -frontend/
    -backend/
    -common/
```

В application.rb есть у config свойство root, но это корень всего проекта, т.е. после его переназначения к примеру app/backend, рельсы начинают искать все файлы который лежат в / приложения в app/backend(что в принципе логично).

Вообще в идеале я рассчитываю по subdomain переназначать путь к app приложения, вроде того:

```
config.path_to_app = case request.subdomain
                          when 'admin' then 'app/backend'
                          when 'api' then 'app/api'
                          else 'app/frontend'
                     end
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться возможно ли разбить приложение таким образом или хотя бы посоветуйте best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой. На помощь пришёл Rails Engine.
Суть в том, что создается встроенное приложение, со своими маршрутами, и файловой структурой. Затем это приложение(Engine) подключается к основному проекту как гем, с указанием пути, где оно находится. А в `routes.rb` основного приложения монтируются маршруты созданного Engine.

Подробнее здесь: http://rusrails.ru/engines

Comment: Спасибо, почитал, отличное решение, обязательно попробую.